# Storing MD5 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, hash, md5

Instead of storing a `MD5 hash` in a 32-byte field, I will like to store it in a 16-byte binary field. Mysql field "TEMP_MD5" is defined as Binary(16).

The MySQL CREATE TABLE with a sample row insert is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `TEMP_MD5` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO mytable (TEMP_MD5) VALUES UNHEX("202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70") );
```

The sample code:

Let's say after the 16-byte binary field has been stored in the MySQL field TEMP_MD5, how do I compare this 16-byte field in Delphi code after I retrieve the value?

Is it possible to skip MySQL HEX/UNHEX internal functions, and just use Delphi code to compare the 16-byte binary field (32-byte string) in MySQL?

For example :

```
FDQuery1.Open( 'SELECT TEMP_MD5 from mytable;' );

if THashMD5.GetHashBytes('123') = fDQuery1.FieldByName('TEMP_MD5').VALUE then
  SHOWMESSAGE('MATCHED!');
```

However, it seems that the values for FieldByName('TEMP_MD5').value never matched the THashMD5.GetHashString('123') value

and another way of comparing by using SELECT statement also failed

```
FDQuery1.Open( 'SELECT TEMP_MD5 mytable ' +
                        'WHERE (TEMP_MD5=:myvalue)',
                               [THashMD5.GetHashBytes('123')] );
```

above also failed to give `FDQuery1.RecordCount = 1`.

Basically I'm trying to compare the 16-byte Binary I stored in MySQL to a value, let's say '123' in code to see if both matches.

I'm using Delphi 10.2 moving to 10.4 next year.

Comment: Add 2-3 examples of hash values which you try to store. Add CREATE TABLE script for `MyTable`.

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify. simple Create Table statement added. thank you.

Comment: You forget to reverse from binary to string. `FDQuery1.Open( 'SELECT LOWER(HEX(TEMP_MD5)) TEMP_MD5 from mytable;' );` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ce3dea7b3933a7cd4c7d23167cc3baf PS. You lost one parenthesis in INSERT INTO - check in the fiddle.

Comment: my apologies. I missed out on parenthesis on the INSERT. oh, yes, I should put back the HEX. thanks!

Comment: Actually, just to clarify, I want to minimise the Server doing a HEX on the field in the SELECT, I'm try to compare the 16-byte binary in Table to a 16 byte binary value given by THashMD5.GetHashBytes('123') ... HEX converts it to 32-byte string again (i believe?) which is what I want to avoid.  Can't I just compare whether the 2 16-byte binary values are the same?

Comment: Akina, don't get me wrong. your code works. thanks & appreciated. just thinking whether I can make it more efficient with a direct comparison of 16-byte data.

Comment: In my opinion, it is much more logical to send a string for testing on MySQL, and get the answer "matched" or "not matched" from it. Of course you may do like you want... but to achieve the same work from two unrelated systems is unnecessary and, I believe, pointless work.

Comment: If you're doing all this just for optimization purposes: it's not worth the effort.

Comment: ok thanks so much for your feedback. In that case, should I just store the MD5 hash field as a 32-byte and do a direct comparison, since a 16-byte Binary(16) is a Blob and there is a blob overhead in storage, and I assume a possible overhead in Blob retrieval as well?

Comment: oh, on second thoughts, since I specified 16-byte for the binary, there should be no overhead in storage unlike a Blob.  I did a quick 'benchmark' - 3000 reads 3.16s for binary16 vs 2.89 for string32. Not much like what you guys say.  Thanks lots.

Comment: Correction : regarding the rough benchmark, it's approximately 3x the time required to do 1 call, so there's quite a bit of difference to get server to do conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of code showing how to write an MD5 into your database and how to read it back and compare with a given MD5 hash:

Inserting data:

```
procedure TForm1.InsertDataButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    MD5    : TArray<Byte>;
begin
    MD5 := THashMD5.GetHashBytes('123');
    FDConnection1.Connected := TRUE;
    FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO mytable (TEMP_MD5) VALUES(:MD5)';
    FDQuery1.ParamByName('MD5').SetBlobRawData(Length(MD5), PByte(MD5));
    FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Rows affected = ' + FDQuery1.RowsAffected.ToString);
end;
```

Reading data back and comparing with given hash:

```
procedure TForm1.ReadDataButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    MD5      : TArray<Byte>;
    MD5_123  : TArray<Byte>;
    FieldMD5 : TField;
    RecCnt   : Integer;
begin
    MD5_123 := THashMD5.GetHashBytes('123');

    FDConnection1.Connected := TRUE;
    // First version: get all records
    // FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT TEMP_MD5 FROM mytable';
    // Second version: Get only records where TEMP_MD5 is hash('123').
    FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT TEMP_MD5 FROM mytable WHERE TEMP_MD5 = :MD5';
    FDQuery1.ParamByName('MD5').SetBlobRawData(Length(MD5_123), PByte(MD5_123));
    // Execute the query
    FDQuery1.Open;
    RecCnt := 0;
    while not FDQuery1.Eof do begin
        Inc(RecCnt);
        FieldMD5 := FDQuery1.FieldByName('TEMP_MD5');
        SetLength(MD5, FieldMD5.DataSize);
        FieldMD5.GetData(MD5);
        if (Length(MD5) = Length(MD5_123)) and
           (CompareMem(PByte(MD5), PByte(MD5_123), Length(MD5))) then
            Memo1.Lines.Add(RecCnt.ToString + ') MD5(123) = ' + MD5ToStr(MD5))
        else
            Memo1.Lines.Add(RecCnt.ToString + ') ' + MD5ToStr(MD5));
        FDQuery1.Next;
    end;
end;
```

As you can see reading the code, I compare the MD5 from database with given MD5 by comparing the memory containing the values (arrays of bytes).

Utility function:

```
function MD5ToStr(MD5 : TArray<Byte>) : String;
var
    B      : Byte;
begin
    Result := '';
    for B in MD5 do
        Result := Result + B.ToHexString(2);
end;
```

Comment: thanks, @fpiette. just curious... there is no simpler way to read a Binary(16) value from table and convert it back to MD5 at run-time?  Something along the line as FDQuery1.FieldByName('TEMP_MD5').AsBytes or something?

Comment: If I can get this to work  FDQuery1.Open( 'SELECT * from mytable WHERE (TEMP_MD5=:myvalue)',[THashMD5.GetHashBytes('123')] )  where both the table Field and my param are 16-byte Binary values, that will also work for me (shorten the code). How to get above to work?

Comment: @PeterJones The ".AsBytes" you request is named ".GetData". And it is a method taking the buffer to store the data. For me it looks as simple: FDQuery1.FieldByName('TEMP_MD5').GetData(MD5); Since I used a TBytes, that is a dynamically allocated datatype, it must be preceded by the necessary code to allocate enough space. The required space is given by DataSize. Since the field is used twice and is a slow method, I saved his value to a variable.

Comment: thanks so much! I have only 1 reputation point now and it requires 15 reputation points to up-vote? will someone please up-vote the answer for now? I promise to come back to up-vote the answer once I cross 15 points!

Comment: I sometimes marvel at how you guys figure out things like SetBlobRawData(Length(MD5_123), PByte(MD5_123))...

Comment: @PeterJones I upvoted your question, which means you now have enough reputation ;-)

Comment: @Olivier  Nice! thanks a lot! I've up-voted the answer and marked it as the answer.

Comment: @fpiette I realised MD5ToStr returns all caps whereas Delphi's THashMD5.GetHashString returns all small caps.  I suppose I can put a Result := lowercase(Result) at the end to compare the two but not sure if there's a more elegant approach (within the md5toStr function code itself) that can directly result in a lowercase?

Comment: @PeterJones Sure you can convert to lowercase. Note that in my sample code, I compare two MD5 hash binary value stored in TBytes, not in string. In that case upper/lower case is not significant. MD5ToStr I wrote is used just for display.